# bootstrap 4.1 removed pull-md-16 (column pull/push)

Tags: bootstrap-4

Need help bootstrap 4.1 removed pull-md-16 (column pull/push)? I tried this.

```
<div class="outer col-md-4 pull-md-16"> </div>
```

need code to overlap 2 columns

Comment: The class `pull-md-16` has *never* existed in standard Bootstrap

Comment: whats the alternate? md-pull don't work either

Comment: i want to over 2 column, its possible in bootstrap 3